# Excel Jet Access Query, Emulate a vlookup

Tags: excel, ms-access, jet

I am trying to incorporate the following logic within my query, which is kind of like 2 vlookups, if one isnt available, use the next.

`=IFERROR(VLOOKUP(D2,'Segmentation'!$A:$C,3,0),IFERROR(VLOOKUP(C2,'Segmentation'!$A:$C,3,0),""))`

So it should lookup into column D First (unit2) then if nothing lookup column C(value)

This is what I have so far, I have tried a `OR` join:

```
SELECT DISTINCT A.[unit], B.[Hierarchy] FROM [Mapping$] as A

inner join [Segmentation$] as B

ON (A.[unit2] = B.[Number] OR
      A.[Value] = B.[Number])

WHERE B.[Hierarchy] <> ''

Order By A.[unit] asc
```

Also tried:

```
SELECT DISTINCT A.[unit], B.[Hierarchy] FROM [Mapping$] as A

inner join [Segmentation$] as B

ON Nz(A.[unit2], A.[Value])=B.[Number]

WHERE B.[Hierarchy] <> ''

Order By A.[unit] asc
```

Sample data in segmentation sheet:

```
+--------------+-------------+-----------+
| Number       |  Name       | Hierarchy |
+--------------+-------------+-----------+
|        11773 | Stack       | Overflow  |
+--------------+-------------+-----------+
```

mapping sheet:

```
+-------+-----------+-------+-------+-----------+---------+
| unit  | variable1 | Value | unit2 | variable2 | value2  |
+-------+-----------+-------+-------+-----------+---------+
| 11773 | lvl0      | 80000 | 11773 | lvl0_nm   | thing 1 |
| 11773 | lvl1      | 89000 | 11773 | lvl1_nm   | thing 2 |
| 11773 | lvl2      | 89022 | 11773 | lvl2_nm   | thing 3 |
| 11773 | lvl3      | 89756 | 11773 | lvl3_nm   | thing 4 |
| 11773 | lvl4      | 89833 | 11773 | lvl4_nm   | thing 5 |
| 11773 | lvl5      | 11773 | 11773 | lvl5_nm   |         |
| 11773 | lvl6      |       | 11773 | lvl6_nm   |         |
| 11773 | lvl7      |       | 11773 | lvl7_nm   |         |
| 11773 | lvl8      |       | 11773 | lvl8_nm   |         |
| 11773 | lvl9      |       | 11773 | lvl9_nm   |         |
| 11773 | lvl10     |       | 11773 | lvl10_nm  |         |
| 11773 | lvl11     |       | 11773 | lvl11_nm  |         |
| 11773 | lvl12     |       | 11773 | lvl12_nm  |         |
| 11773 | lvl13     |       | 11773 | lvl13_nm  |         |
| 11773 | lvl14     |       | 11773 | lvl14_nm  |         |
| 11773 | lvl15     |       | 11773 | lvl15_nm  |         |
| 11773 | lvl16     |       | 11773 | lvl16_nm  |         |
| 11773 | lvl17     |       | 11773 | lvl17_nm  |         |
| 11773 | lvl18     |       | 11773 | lvl18_nm  |         |
+-------+-----------+-------+-------+-----------+---------+
```

expected outcome:

```
+-------+-----------+-------+-------+-----------+---------+-----------+
| unit  | variable1 | Value | unit2 | variable2 | value2  | Hierarchy |
+-------+-----------+-------+-------+-----------+---------+-----------+
| 11773 | lvl0      | 80000 | 11773 | lvl0_nm   | thing 1 | Overflow  |
| 11773 | lvl1      | 89000 | 11773 | lvl1_nm   | thing 2 | Overflow  |
| 11773 | lvl2      | 89022 | 11773 | lvl2_nm   | thing 3 | Overflow  |
| 11773 | lvl3      | 89756 | 11773 | lvl3_nm   | thing 4 | Overflow  |
| 11773 | lvl4      | 89833 | 11773 | lvl4_nm   | thing 5 | Overflow  |
| 11773 | lvl5      | 11773 | 11773 | lvl5_nm   |         | Overflow  |
| 11773 | lvl6      |       | 11773 | lvl6_nm   |         | Overflow  |
| 11773 | lvl7      |       | 11773 | lvl7_nm   |         | Overflow  |
| 11773 | lvl8      |       | 11773 | lvl8_nm   |         | Overflow  |
| 11773 | lvl9      |       | 11773 | lvl9_nm   |         | Overflow  |
| 11773 | lvl10     |       | 11773 | lvl10_nm  |         | Overflow  |
| 11773 | lvl11     |       | 11773 | lvl11_nm  |         | Overflow  |
| 11773 | lvl12     |       | 11773 | lvl12_nm  |         | Overflow  |
| 11773 | lvl13     |       | 11773 | lvl13_nm  |         | Overflow  |
| 11773 | lvl14     |       | 11773 | lvl14_nm  |         | Overflow  |
| 11773 | lvl15     |       | 11773 | lvl15_nm  |         | Overflow  |
| 11773 | lvl16     |       | 11773 | lvl16_nm  |         | Overflow  |
| 11773 | lvl17     |       | 11773 | lvl17_nm  |         | Overflow  |
| 11773 | lvl18     |       | 11773 | lvl18_nm  |         | Overflow  |
+-------+-----------+-------+-------+-----------+---------+-----------+
```

Sample if first vlookup failed:

```
+--------+-------+-----------+
| Number | Name  | Hierarchy |
+--------+-------+-----------+
|  82282 | Super | User      |
+--------+-------+-----------+
```

mapping sheet

```
+-------+-----------+-------+-------+-----------+----------+
| unit  | variable1 | Value | unit2 | variable2 |  value2  |
+-------+-----------+-------+-------+-----------+----------+
| 96702 | lvl0      | 80000 | 96702 | lvl0_nm   | thing 6  |
| 96702 | lvl1      | 80393 | 96702 | lvl1_nm   | thing 7  |
| 96702 | lvl2      | 85176 | 96702 | lvl2_nm   | thing 8  |
| 96702 | lvl3      | 82282 | 96702 | lvl3_nm   | thing 9  |
| 96702 | lvl4      | 87927 | 96702 | lvl4_nm   | thing 10 |
| 96702 | lvl5      | 88172 | 96702 | lvl5_nm   | thing 11 |
| 96702 | lvl6      | 81025 | 96702 | lvl6_nm   | thing 12 |
| 96702 | lvl7      | 96702 | 96702 | lvl7_nm   |          |
| 96702 | lvl8      |       | 96702 | lvl8_nm   |          |
| 96702 | lvl9      |       | 96702 | lvl9_nm   |          |
| 96702 | lvl10     |       | 96702 | lvl10_nm  |          |
| 96702 | lvl11     |       | 96702 | lvl11_nm  |          |
| 96702 | lvl12     |       | 96702 | lvl12_nm  |          |
| 96702 | lvl13     |       | 96702 | lvl13_nm  |          |
| 96702 | lvl14     |       | 96702 | lvl14_nm  |          |
| 96702 | lvl15     |       | 96702 | lvl15_nm  |          |
| 96702 | lvl16     |       | 96702 | lvl16_nm  |          |
| 96702 | lvl17     |       | 96702 | lvl17_nm  |          |
| 96702 | lvl18     |       | 96702 | lvl18_nm  |          |
+-------+-----------+-------+-------+-----------+----------+
```

expected outcome:

```
+-------+-----------+-------+-------+-----------+----------+-----------+
| unit  | variable1 | Value | unit2 | variable2 |  value2  | Hierarchy |
+-------+-----------+-------+-------+-----------+----------+-----------+
| 96702 | lvl0      | 80000 | 96702 | lvl0_nm   | thing 6  |           |
| 96702 | lvl1      | 80393 | 96702 | lvl1_nm   | thing 7  |           |
| 96702 | lvl2      | 85176 | 96702 | lvl2_nm   | thing 8  |           |
| 96702 | lvl3      | 82282 | 96702 | lvl3_nm   | thing 9  | User      |
| 96702 | lvl4      | 87927 | 96702 | lvl4_nm   | thing 10 |           |
| 96702 | lvl5      | 88172 | 96702 | lvl5_nm   | thing 11 |           |
| 96702 | lvl6      | 81025 | 96702 | lvl6_nm   | thing 12 |           |
| 96702 | lvl7      | 96702 | 96702 | lvl7_nm   |          |           |
| 96702 | lvl8      |       | 96702 | lvl8_nm   |          |           |
| 96702 | lvl9      |       | 96702 | lvl9_nm   |          |           |
| 96702 | lvl10     |       | 96702 | lvl10_nm  |          |           |
| 96702 | lvl11     |       | 96702 | lvl11_nm  |          |           |
| 96702 | lvl12     |       | 96702 | lvl12_nm  |          |           |
| 96702 | lvl13     |       | 96702 | lvl13_nm  |          |           |
| 96702 | lvl14     |       | 96702 | lvl14_nm  |          |           |
| 96702 | lvl15     |       | 96702 | lvl15_nm  |          |           |
| 96702 | lvl16     |       | 96702 | lvl16_nm  |          |           |
| 96702 | lvl17     |       | 96702 | lvl17_nm  |          |           |
| 96702 | lvl18     |       | 96702 | lvl18_nm  |          |           |
+-------+-----------+-------+-------+-----------+----------+-----------+
```

Comment: It's not clear what problem you are having.  Please show us what your data looks like and what result you are seeking.  Good questions tend to provide [minimal, complete, verifiable examples](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

Comment: Try:`ON Nz(A.[Unit], A.[Value])=B.[Number]`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your code,

```
SELECT 
    DISTINCT A.[unit],
    B.[Hierarchy] 
FROM [Mapping$] as A inner join [Segmentation$] as B ON (A.[unit2] = B.[Number] OR A.[Value] = B.[Number])
WHERE B.[Hierarchy] <> ''    
Order By A.[unit] asc;
```

Since you are using `Inner Join` you don't need `WHERE B.[Hierarchy] <> ''`. The join will produce result only if there is a match.

to get your expected outcome, you could either use `LEFT JOIN` or subquery.

```
SELECT 
    DISTINCT A.[unit],
    B.[Hierarchy] 
FROM [Mapping$] as A **LEFT JOIN** [Segmentation$] as B ON (A.[unit2] = B.[Number] OR A.[Value] = B.[Number])
Order By A.[unit] asc;
```

This will produce list of Unique `A.Unit` and `B.Hierarchy` if available.

You can also use subqueries. (If `segmentation.Number` is not unique, **use Top 1.** Otherwise your subquery will return more than one row and complain about it)

```
SELECT 
    A.*,
    (SELECT B.[Hierarchy] 
     FROM [Segmentation$] as B
     WHERE (A.[unit2] = B.[Number] OR A.[Value] = B.[Number])) AS Hierarchy
FROM [Mapping$] as A
Order By A.[unit] asc;
```

Comment: @JonnyBoy you might have to add index in order to improve performances

Comment: What do you mean add index? Can you show me what you mean?

Comment: @JonnyBoy  [AddIndex]("https://www.google.com/search?client=firefox-b-d&q=add+index+in+ms+access")